# Remote Web Workplace for Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs

I need to perform a transition from a Windows Server 2008 SBS domain to a "regular" Windows Server 2008 R2 domain with Exchange. One SBS-specific feature users are relying on is Remote Web Workplace. I still cannot make out if it is possible to install it as an addon to a "regular" Windows Server with IIS.

[This blog post](http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-to-install-remote-web-workplace-on-windows-server-2008.html) suggests it is possible to extract the feature by running remoteww.msi off the Remote Operations Manager CD off System Center Essentials 2007. The System Center suite has been updated since - does this still apply? Are there licensing concerns? Any hints for alternate approaches appreciated.

Note: I am not after the Remote Desktop Gateway feature, I know how to install/configure that. I would need the portal site itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no such thing. As events are turning currently, the *Essentials* edition of Windows Server 2012 due to be released towards the end of 2012 will have a web portal resembling the one of Small Business Server and it will remain functional upon transition to the *Standard* edition:

> After you have transitioned to Windows Server 2012 Standard, the Windows Server 2012 Essentials limits are removed [...]. The Essentials features will still be there with the exception of the media features, which no longer work due to technical limitations.

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2012/08/06/growing-beyond-25-users-with-windows-server-2012-essentials.aspx

So this is likely the route I am going to suggest for the network in question.